# No se define una variable calculadora en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, variables

Buen día, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en python usando `tkinter`, el problema esta en lo siguiente:

Al refactorizar el coódigo, creo una variable `calculadora = Calculadora`, y me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

```
"calculadora = Calculadora(messagebox) NameError: name 'Calculadora' is not defined"
```

Dejo el código, para ver si alguien dispone de tiempo y puede ayudarme, de antemano gracias!

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class Calculadora:
    
    def __init__(self, alertas):
        self.numero1 = StringVar()
        self.numero2 = StringVar()
        self.resultado = StringVar()
        self.alertas = alertas
        
    def cFloat(self, numero):
        try:
            result = float(numero)
        except:
            result = 0
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Introduce bien los datos")
            
        return result

    def sumar(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) + self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()
        
    def restar(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) - self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()
        
    def multiplicar(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) * self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()
        
    def dividir(self):
        self.resultado.set(self.cFloat(self.numero1.get()) / self.cFloat(self.numero2.get()))
        self.mostrarResultado()
        
    def mostrarResultado(self):
        self.alertas.showinfo("Resultado", f"El resultado de la operacion es: {self.resultado.get()}")
        self.numero1.set("")
        self.numero2.set("")

    ventana = Tk()
    ventana.title("Ejercicio completo con Tkinter | José Gutierrez")
    ventana.geometry("400x400")
    ventana.config(bd=25)
    
    calculadora = Calculadora(messagebox)

    marco = Frame(ventana, width=340, height=200)
    marco.config(
        padx=15,
        pady=15,
        bd=5,
        relief=SOLID,
    ) 
    marco.pack(side=TOP, anchor=CENTER)
    marco.pack_propagate(False)

    Label(marco, text="Primer número: ").pack()
    Entry(marco, textvariable=calculadora.numero1, justify="center").pack()

    Label(marco, text="Segundo número: ").pack()
    Entry(marco, textvariable=calculadora.numero2, justify="center").pack()

    Label(marco, text="").pack()

    Button(marco, text="Sumar", command=calculadora.sumar).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES)
    Button(marco, text="Restar", command=calculadora.restar).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES)
    Button(marco, text="Multiplicar", command=calculadora.multiplicar).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES)
    Button(marco, text="Dividir", command=calculadora.dividir).pack(side="left", fill=X, expand=YES)

    ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si tu indentacion en tu código original es igual al código publicado, diria que el error se debe a que el código principal esta dentro de la clase calculadora. Es decir, intentas llamar a la clase calculadora antes de que siquiera se termine de crear y guardar el objeto creado en una variable

Comment: La solución? Coloca el código principal con 4 espacios menos (es decir, sacalo de la clase calculadora)

Comment: Gracias  @DanteS.  por la ayuda, resuelto el inconveniente, saludos!

Comment: De nada jjavier c: